# Is this the correct DRY way to test user roles with RSpec & Shoulda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan, shoulda

I have a rails application using cancan, and there are several different roles that I am testing. I'm looking for the most DRY way to setup these tests across several controllers.

This is a shortened version of what I have so far. Is there a better way to do this? It still feels kinda heavy to me.

```
describe OrganizationsController do
  render_views

  before do
    # User roles
    @unauthenticated = User.new
    @org_admin = Factory.create(:organization_admin)
    @org_staff = Factory.create(:org_staff)
    @customer = Factory.create(:customer)
    @admin = Factory.create(:admin)

    @organization = Factory.create(:organization)
    @org_for_admin = Factory.create(:organization, :user_group_id => @org_admin.user_group_id)
    @org_attr = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:organization)
  end

  describe "GET 'show'" do
    authorized = %w(org_admin admin org_staff customer)
    not_authorized = %w(unauthenticated)

    not_authorized.each do |u|
      context "an organization by a user with role: #{u}" do
        before do
          user = instance_variable_get("@#{u}")
          get :show, :id => @organization.id, :format => 'json'
        end
        it { should_not respond_with :success }
        it { should respond_with :forbidden }
      end
    end

    authorized.each do |u|
      context "an organization by a user with role: #{u}" do
        before do
          user = instance_variable_get("@#{u}")
          get :show, :id => @organization.id, :format => 'json', :token => user.token
        end
        it { should respond_with :success }
        it { should render_template :show }
        it { should respond_with_content_type(/json/) }
        it { should assign_to(:organization).with_kind_of(Organization) }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'update'" do
    authorized = [%w(admin organization), %w(org_admin org_for_admin)]
    not_authorized = [%w(unauthenticated organization), %w(org_staff org_for_admin), %w(customer organization), %w(org_admin organization)]
    not_authorized.each do |u, o|
      context "an organization by a user with role: #{u}" do
        before do
          user = instance_variable_get("@#{u}")
          organization = instance_variable_get("@#{o}")
          put :update, :id => organization.id, :organization => @org_attr, :format => 'json'
        end
        it { should_not respond_with :success }
        it { should respond_with :forbidden }
      end
    end

    authorized.each do |u, o|
      context "an organization by a user with role: #{u}" do
        before do
          user = instance_variable_get("@#{u}")
          organization = instance_variable_get("@#{o}")          
          put :update, :id => organization.id, :organization => @org_attr, :format => 'json', :token => user.token
        end
        it { should respond_with :success }
        it { should render_template :update }
        it { should respond_with_content_type(/json/) }
        it { should assign_to(:organization).with_kind_of(Organization) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Or, should I be using the cancan matchers and move these types of ability tests into the model specs and just have a successful and a forbidden test for each controller action? Any other comments on my tests in terms of anti-patterns/stylistic suggestions are also welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities) describes the "pain point" you're feeling:

> It can be difficult to thoroughly test user permissions at the
>   functional/integration level because there are often many branching
>   possibilities.
>
> .. if you want to test the controller behavior
>   independently from what is inside the Ability class, it is easy to
>   stub out the ability with any behavior you want.

```
def setup
  @ability = Object.new
  @ability.extend(CanCan::Ability)
  @controller.stubs(:current_ability).returns(@ability)
end

test "render index if have read ability on project" do
  @ability.can :read, Project
  get :index
  assert_template :index
end
```

Good question.  I've often wondered this myself.  Next time, I'm going to try the wiki's suggestion.

Comment: That does look much cleaner. Thanks!